# D3.js - How to use different styles for tick labels in one plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js for ploting data. On x axis I have time in various ranges.

So the tick labels could look like that:

[image]

I would like to emphasize the years, so I would like to have year labels bold, while months will stay not bold.

I have not found a solution. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After creating the axis svg nodes with the `.call` to axis component, you can go back and select specific text nodes to change their styling.

In this example I'm simply checking which of the axis nodes parse to a number, which is true only of the year values:

```
axisNodes.selectAll('text').each(function() {
  if(+this.textContent) {
    this.classList.add("year");
  }
});
```

And then the 'year' css class can apply whatever extra styling you want.

```js
//adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176
var margin = {top: 250, right: 40, bottom: 250, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date(2013, 0, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var axisNodes = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,50)")
    .call(xAxis);

axisNodes.selectAll('text').each(function() {
  if(+this.textContent) {
    this.classList.add("year");
  }
});
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.year {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```